# Oracle stored procedure to return rowset as out parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need some help regarding my procedure where I need to return a table like structure from an Oracle stored procedure.

My requirements are as follows:

1. My project will have one master procedure which will be called from the external system
2. The procedure will call multiple functions from inside which will return a value. Like **Function_1 return 10** & **Function_2 return 20**
3. Now after receiving this value I need to return the data to the calling method of procedure as KEY VALUE structure. Like

   ```
   KEY        | VALUE
   -----------+-----------
   Function_1 |  10
   Function_2 |  20
   ```

My constraint is I can not create a temporary table to achieve this functionality. So, I saw one option with ref cursor but how to populate the cursor with this value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statements for your tables and your attempt at creating the procedure and any error messages or a description of where it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: I didn't write the procedure. Looking for the approach to do that. So, if you can provide any example that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pipelined function (rather than procedure):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE KeyValuePair AS Object(
  key   VARCHAR2(20),
  value NUMBER(8)
);
/
CREATE TYPE KeyValuePairList AS TABLE OF KeyValuePair;
/
CREATE FUNCTION function1 RETURN NUMBER AS BEGIN RETURN 10; END;
/
CREATE FUNCTION function2 RETURN NUMBER AS BEGIN RETURN 20; END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION mainFunc RETURN KeyValuePairList PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  PIPE ROW ( KeyValuePair( 'FUNCTION1', function1() ) );
  PIPE ROW ( KeyValuePair( 'FUNCTION2', function2() ) );
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( mainFunc() );
```

**Output**:

```
KEY       | VALUE
:-------- | ----:
FUNCTION1 |    10
FUNCTION2 |    20
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59cbee9c6a09ffead83396a27459e7ab)*

---

Or as a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mainFunc (
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT 'FUNCTION1'  AS key, function1() AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FUNCTION2'  AS key, function2() AS value FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd42b0b2a846c6c72de65a4b2810ed1d)*

Comment: Can we make 'mainFunc()' as procedure? 
Also many thread calls the maninFunc(). So, will be there any concurrency issue.
Just for curosity- Is tehre any way to do it through the cursor